# Changing font color while adding row in exceljs

Tags: exceljs

As per the documentation, Changing font color of a particular cell is possible in this way:

```
sheet.addRow([
    'alex', 
    {
        text: 'image',
        hyperlink: 'http://something.com' //trying to change color of this cell
    }
])

sheet.getRow(1).getCell(2).font = {color: {argb: "004e47cc"}};
```

But, How do i specify styles while adding a row itself. (something like below).

```
sheet.addRow([
    'alex', 
    {
        text: 'image', 
        hyperlink: 'http://something.com', 
        font: {color: {argb: '004e47cc'}}
    }
])
```

My ultimate goal is to change color and underline all Hyperlinks in the sheet (**Hyperlinks are in random cells). Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This works:

```
sheet.eachRow(function(row, rowNumber){
    row.eachCell( function(cell, colNumber){
        if(cell.value && cell.value.hyperlink)
            row.getCell(colNumber).font = {color: {argb: "004e47cc"}};
    });
});
```

Comment: So it wasn't possible when creating the row?

Comment: @SamuelMéndez As per the documentation, NO.

Comment: Currently you can, check on the code_kbd answer below. Remeber the colors should not have #

Answer (score 8):

It is indeed possible to change the background color when adding a row;

```
let row = workSheet.addRow(rowValues);
            row.fill = {
                type: 'pattern',
                pattern:'solid',
                fgColor:{argb:'#000000'},
                bgColor:{argb:'#FF0000'}
            };
```

Comment: For the colors use them without the # otherwise youll get a black background color. SO it should be something like row1.fill = {
                    type: 'pattern',
                    pattern:'solid',
                    fgColor: { argb:'FFFF0000' }

                };

Comment: thanks for the comment @geoff. I did not edit the answer since your comment makes it very clear. In my case, I wanted a black solid color, so I really did not notice it.

Comment: Hi @code_kbd, i am trying to do something similar, where i am reading from one excel and writing to another excel with using `addRow`. Do you know how i can copy the cell styling when adding row? here is the question link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65309694/styles-not-getting-copied-from-source-excel-file any help would be really great, Thanks.

Comment: this is not working. We need to loop through all the cells in that row and then add the font property to it. That is the only working solution as of now.

Comment: Hi code_kbd. Given @Geoff's comment (I agree with that comment -- the code in that comment worked for me) I think you should update your answer. I tried your answer first and couldn't get it to work, wasted time. I would say your answer is really just incorrect, fwiw. If you update your answer, I'll upvoted it.