# styles not getting copied from source excel file

Tags: javascript, node.js, exceljs

I am trying to read -> manipulate -> create excel. I am using `streams` supported by `exceljs` module. most of it is working fine, but the styles do not seem to be copied over. Below is my relevant part of the code.

```
const readerOptions = {
 sharedStrings: 'cache',
 hyperlinks: 'cache',
 worksheets: 'emit',
 styles: 'cache',
};
const writerOptions = {
  filename: fpath,
  useStyles: true,
  useSharedStrings: true
}
const workbook = new ExcelJS.stream.xlsx.WorkbookWriter(writerOptions)
const myworksheet = workbook.addWorksheet('Sheet 1');
const workbookReader = new ExcelJS.stream.xlsx.WorkbookReader(sheet.path, readerOptions);
workbookReader.read();
workbookReader.on('worksheet', worksheet => {
  worksheet.on('row', row => {
    myworksheet.addRow(row.values).commit();
  });
});

workbookReader.on('end', async () => {
 await workbook.commit();
});
workbookReader.on('error', (err) => {
 console.log(err);
});
```

please see the attached image for your reference. On left is the source excel file from which I am trying to manipulate and generate another excel and on right is the newly generated excel file from the source.

[image]

Any help on how to fix this will be really great, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone stumbling on this post, below fix worked for me.

```
const readerOptions = {
sharedStrings: 'cache',
 hyperlinks: 'cache',
 worksheets: 'emit',
 styles: 'cache',
};
const writerOptions = {
 filename: fpath,
 useStyles: true,
 useSharedStrings: true
}
const workbook = new ExcelJS.stream.xlsx.WorkbookWriter(writerOptions)
const myworksheet = workbook.addWorksheet('Sheet 1');
const workbookReader = new ExcelJS.stream.xlsx.WorkbookReader(sheet.path, readerOptions);
workbookReader.read();
workbookReader.on('worksheet', worksheet => {
 worksheet.on('row', row => {
  const r = myworksheet.addRow();
  Object.assign(r, row);
 });
});

workbookReader.on('end', async () => {
 await workbook.commit();
});
```

This copied the rows with all the correct styling information. (One issue, i am still facing is this does not work well with rows with merged cells)